# Breakpoints don't get hit while debugging the client of a NextJS 12 app in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js

I have an issue with debugging NextJS 12 apps in VSCode. Basically, the breakpoints ain't triggered when reloading in the browser.

- Create the default NextJS 12 app using: `$ npx create-next-app@latest`.
- Create the `launch.json` using https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Start the app with `$ npm run dev`
- Set a breakpoint at the `pages/index.js:10` for example.
- Run the debug session and see how the breakpoint is getting hit.
- Now if you reload the page, the breakpoing isn't going to be hit. Why?

The only way to get it triggered again is to restart the debugging session OR edit the file with the breakpoint.

Ideas?
Is there a sort of optimization which can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation from Next JS can be found here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging)

The example illustrates 3 ways to connect:

1. Server side
2. Client side
3. Full stack

For your case, since it's `page/index.js` (client-side) I would suggest the second option or the 3rd option.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```